# website check if user is already login in facebook?

Tags: facebook, social-networking

I dont want any code. just wana know that is it possible that a website checks if a user is already login in facebook and if yes shows link to facebook page and if not avoid bothering user with that. if I wana do that with other services such as twitter, youtube, ... there would be so many buttons and that's why I want to avoid showing all if user does not have those account.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. Websites know that you are already authenticated based on cookies, basically, which are per domain. One domain cannot access another domain's cookies.

EDIT:  in the case of Facebook, you probably could use their API to check whether the user is logged in: [Facebook API - Check Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#checklogin). Most likely other social platforms have something similar.

Comment: true, but user is not using any app!

Comment: But the check would be made in your website, not in any app the user could be using.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely would have to have a code on your site to check if the user is able to bypass the login page on facebook.  If they are able to bypass the login page then more than likely they are logged into facebook.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function fbstatus() {
FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function() {
// Create an ApiClient object, passing app's API key and 
// a site relative URL to xd_receiver.htm
FB.Facebook.init(api_key, channel_path);
FB.Connect.get_status().waitUntilReady(function(status) {
   switch(status) {
   case FB.ConnectState.connected:
       //FACEBOOK - LOGGED IN AUTHORIZED           
   break;
   case FB.ConnectState.appNotAuthorized:
       //FACEBOOK - LOGGED IN NOT AUTHORIZED           
   break;
   case FB.ConnectState.userNotLoggedIn:
       //FACEBOOK - NOT LOGGED IN FACEBOOK           
   break;
   }
 });
```

});
}

Here is the code for checking user is loggedin in facebook on other tab of the browser.

Comment: Hey Andrew ...have nothing better to do ?  yeah the question is not brilliantly written but hey 3 people + me understood perfectly what the question is and even answered it ... if you want stricktly perfect written questions go talk to your computer or buy a book...your ideal of people talking/writing like robots will never exist...if you are frustrated and need to feel good go irritate your neigbours !